# How to pull the first block of its kind from a Matrix?

Tags: matrix, filter, blocks

This is a news feed with a title, image and short blurb beneath. The entry content is built with the Matrix. An entry can be made up of a single 'textEditorBlock' or multiple 'textEditorBlock'.

**I just want to return the first 'textEditorBlock' from Matrix.** Currently, all existing 'textEditorBlock' blocks get returned.

```
{# Count the number of Matrix Blocks; type: textEditorBlock  #}
{% set blocks = post.buildStory.type('textEditorBlock') %}
{{ blocks | length }}

{% for block in post.buildStory.all() %}
   {# the text #}
   {% set paragraphs = block.textEditor %}
   {% set teaser = paragraphs | length > 75 ? paragraphs | slice(0, 250) ~ '...' :  paragraphs %}
   <p>{{  teaser  | striptags | raw | typogrify  }}</p>       
{% endfor %}
```

Note: the {{ blocks | length }} tells me the number of 'textEditorBlock' that exist for each entry (1, 4, 4, 2 and 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
{% set block = post.buildStory.type('textEditorBlock').first() %}
    {{block.textEditor}}
```

Comment: That's it! Solution:

`{% set blocks = entry.buildStory.type('textEditorBlock').one() %}
{% set paragraphs = blocks.textEditor %}
{% set teaser = paragraphs | length > 75 ? paragraphs | slice(0, 250) ~ '...' :  paragraphs %}
<p>{{  teaser  | striptags | raw | typogrify  }}</p>`

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
{% set blocks = post.buildStory.type('textEditorBlock').limit(1) %}
```

Also, not your question, but this hacksaw port is great for those teasers.  Has some extra logic to make those a bit cleaner.  Check it out.

https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw